# pyCurl checking if SSPI is enabled

Tags: python, curl, pycurl, sspi

The default build of `pycurl` from what I understand does not support `SSPI` and also is built against a very old version of libcurl ~ 7.19. So I have gone ahead and made my own build of this library.

I have installed the new `libcurl` and `pycurl` source on my machine and the version information confirms it has been built correctly. Using the WINDOWS_SSPI flag.

```
> pycurl.version
'libcurl/7.31.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8y zlib/1.2.8'
```

The libcurl version is now showing 7.31.0. But I cannot see if SSPI is enabled. Running version info from pycurl gives me.

```
(3, '7.31.0', 466688, 'i386-pc-win32', 2748, 'OpenSSL/0.9.8y', 0, '1.2.8',
('dict', 'file', 'ftp', 'ftps', 'gopher', 'http', 'https', 'imap', 'imaps', 'ldap',
'pop3', 'pop3s', 'rtsp', 'smtp', 'smtps', 'telnet', 'tftp'), None, 0, None)
```

But still no indication of whether SSPI has been enabled.